# Rails routing redirect if slug not correct

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my Rails app I have posts and they have a route like so:

```
match '/posts/:id' => 'posts#show', :via => :get, :as => :post
```

In my model I have:

```
def to_param
  "#{id}/#{slug}"
end
```

So that I can have a pretty URL like:

```
/posts/1/This-is-a-post
```

However the **first issue** I have is that the `/` between the `id` and `slug` gets encoded! So I end up with: `/posts/1%2FThis-is-a-post`

The **second issue** I have, is that it doesn't matter what I put as the slug, it will ALWAYS show the post. While this isn't bad, it means the URL integrity is lost as the same post can have many variations.

What I'd like to do is make it work like on Stack Overflow, where if a user hits any of these URLs

```
/posts/1
/posts/1/This-is-a
/posts/1/this_is-A-PoSt
/posts/1/sifiusfheud
```

it will auto-redirect to

```
/posts/1/This-is-a-post
```

How can I do this in Rails? And can I do it using the `to_param`? Or will I have to do something custom?

Comment: Using either IDs _or_ slugs (but not both at the same time) seems to be more compatible with the Rails way (and it'll be a bit simpler to implement). I'd recommend you reconsider this approach. If you still want to use `:id/:slug` then would using a hyphen as a separate work? (So you'd have `1234-rails-rocks` instead of `1234/rails-rocks`) If so that'd make it much simpler.

Comment: @Cameron. Why would you post a question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41395692/get-records-by-year-and-month-in-rails-using-sqlite) and delete it just after someone took the time to write a valid answer?

Answer (score 1):

How about having a route like this?

```
get '/posts/:id/:slug' => 'posts#show', as: :post_with_slug
```

and then use it in a view like

```
= link_to 'Post...', post_with_slug_path(:id @post.id, slug: @post.slug)
```

You could then do some checking of the spelling in the controller and route to the correct spelling of the post.

Then there is also the `friendly_id` gem that is quite useful.

Comment: Wouldn't I need two routes? One with just `:id` and one with `:id/:slug` and have the controller redirect to the latter if the slug doesn't match correctly, but behind the scenes it's just matching on the id to find it.

Comment: Depends on your usage, if all links have a slug you can just grab the `id` and check if the `slug` matches the real slug, redirect if not.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have come up with (inspired by Iceman's comments).

Two routes:

```
match '/posts/:id' => 'posts#show', :via => :get, :as => :post
match '/posts/:id/:slug' => 'posts#show', :via => :get, :as => :post_with_slug
```

And then use the `post_with_slug` for the links:

```
<%= link_to post.title, post_with_slug_path(id: post.id, slug: post.slug) %>
```

But then took it further with a helper:

```
def post_with_slug(post)
  "/posts/#{[post.id, post.slug].join('/')}"
end
```

So I could just pass the object:

```
<%= link_to post.title, post_with_slug(post) %>
```

Finally redirect if the slug param doesn't match.

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to post_with_slug_path(id: @post.id, slug: @post.slug), :status => 301 if @post.slug != params[:slug]
end
```

This looks to work really well, and even handles if the slash between the slug and ID is missing or different and always redirects the user to the correct url. I added a 301 status, just in case a user had used in an incorrect or old slug for SEO purposes.